# ontouchenter and ontouchleave in Blazor component not firing

Tags: asp.net, blazor

The Microsoft documentation mentions the @ontouchenter and @ontouchleave events.

I would like to utilize these to enable drag and drop in my Blazor app, but it doesn't seem like these events are firing. There is not a lot of examples of other mentions on the web.

Does anyone know whether they are supposed to work? Do I need to do any special to make them work?

**UPDATE**
I think it is because the element position is not changed, as the normal draggable ensures via mouse drag.

Is it possible to change/update the elements position (x,y) via c# in Blazor?

**Example**
The following is a minimal example

Index.razor

```
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div style="height: 300px;width: 300px;background-color: cornflowerblue;touch-action: none; border: medium;"
     ondragover="event.preventDefault();"        
     @ontouchenter="OnTouch"
     @ontouchleave="OnTouch"         
     @ondragenter="OnDrag"
     @ondragleave="OnDrag"
     @ondrop="OnDrop">
    Drag to Me
</div>

<DragItem></DragItem>
<DragItem></DragItem>
<DragItem></DragItem>
<DragItem></DragItem>

@code{
    private void OnTouch(TouchEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index:OnTouch:" + args.Type);
    }

    void OnDrag(DragEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index:OnDrag:" + args.Type);
    }

    void OnDrop(DragEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Index:OnDrop:" + args.Type);
    }
}
```

DragItem.razor

```
<div       
     draggable="true"
     @ontouchmove="OnTouchMove"
     style=" cursor: move;
        background-color: cornflowerblue;
        touch-action: none;
        user-select: none;
        border: medium;
        min-height: 100px;
        min-width: 100px">
    DragMe
</div>

@code {
private void OnTouch(TouchEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnTouch:" + args.Type);
    }

    private void OnTouchMove(TouchEventArgs args)
    {
        //double x = args.ChangedTouches[0].ClientX;
        //double y = args.ChangedTouches[0].ClientY;
        //--> I guess this is where I should update my dragitem position
        //--> Normal drag via mouse automatically updates position, but not touchMove
    }

    void OnDrag(DragEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnDrag:" + args.Type);
    }

    void OnDrop(DragEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnDrop:" + args.Type);
    }

    void StoryClicked()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("StoryClicked");
    }
}
```

Comment: An [mcve] might be useful.

Comment: Here is a Blazor fiddle where I've added JS funktion to update the UI (I don't know how to do this via Blazor on OnTouchMove). The OnTouchEnter and OnTouchLeave events are not triggerede on the index page - only when using a mouse https://blazorfiddle.com/s/y7dgrvgq - See event output via console